# Is there a way to get good performance in Rails without losing the ability to debug and develop code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was put on the task to speed up the response times of an API run on Ruby on Rails (3.0.9).

All requests are sent in xml, and the response times were horrible. Acceptable response times would be <100ms, but I was experiencing 130-4000ms, averaging around 1100ms.

This was even after I had...

- Optimized all MySQL indexes (through the slow query log black magic)
- Installed fast_xs (Since it was the main advice to speed up xml generation)
- Analyzed the log/production.log using request-log-analyzer and not found any particular problem area (ie it seems as all requests are rather evenly slow all together)
- Drawn the conclusion that since it is a rather powerful server (midrange), there should be any issue with the hardware...

Example of request durations:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1355ms (Views: 814.7ms | ActiveRecord: 217.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 138ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 327ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 317ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 413ms (Views: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 47.9ms)
Completed 201 Created in 2281ms (Views: 8.9ms | ActiveRecord: 324.7ms)
Completed 201 Created in 2249ms (Views: 37.4ms | ActiveRecord: 261.1ms)
Completed 201 Created in 1010ms (Views: 8.5ms | ActiveRecord: 222.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1285ms (Views: 644.0ms | ActiveRecord: 224.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 135ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 459ms (Views: 6.3ms | ActiveRecord: 66.2ms)
Completed 201 Created in 1621ms (Views: 56.8ms | ActiveRecord: 412.0ms)
Completed 201 Created in 1716ms (Views: 57.1ms | ActiveRecord: 367.9ms)
Completed 201 Created in 1118ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 292.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1355ms (Views: 871.6ms | ActiveRecord: 153.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 300ms (Views: 263.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1338ms (Views: 6.4ms | ActiveRecord: 227.7ms)
Completed 201 Created in 927ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 188.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1458ms (Views: 827.4ms | ActiveRecord: 259.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 182ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 261ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

Horrible... Then... After ensuring that production configuration is used (incl config.cache_classes = true, config.log_level = :info), it changed to the following:

```
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
Completed 201 Created in 126ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
Completed 201 Created in 30ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
Completed 201 Created in 11ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
Completed 201 Created in 18ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
Completed 201 Created in 16ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 115ms (Views: 26.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
Completed 201 Created in 23ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
Completed 201 Created in 11ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
Completed 201 Created in 16ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 16ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
Completed 201 Created in 16ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
Completed 201 Created in 17ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
Completed 201 Created in 15ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
Completed 201 Created in 15ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 79ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 8.4ms)
Completed 201 Created in 18ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

Bottom line: If you are seeing bad Rails performance while developing, turn on production configuration and see what you get before giving up on Rails :)

This leads to the question: Is there a way to get good performance in Rails without needing to put on production settings and thus loosing the ability to debug and develop code in an efficient manner? Is https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost best practice?

Comment: How much performance do you need in *development* mode?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that most of the increase in speed is due to the class cache. In development mode, classes are recompiled everytime a member is called. If you have a lot of code, you can imagine that this will take some time. By caching those classes you've effectively eliminated the wait time between request and execution. The side effect, of course, is that changes to the code aren't recognized until the server is restarted. The real question is, why are you changing code on a running production server? This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: To clarify, I am not interested in developing in a live environment, that would be insane :) It's just that this API is used together with a web application under development, and with 10-12 requests per page load there is quite a difference having the page load in 5-7 seconds extra per page load vs less than half a second.
Is there maybe something like an opcode cache, or some way to only recompile the classes in the files that has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what your issue is: on your production machine, use a production Rails environment, and use a development environment on your dev machine...

From what you're saying in your post, it seems like your problems stems from wanting to develop directly on your production instance. This is a bad idea in general, and certainly NOT "the Rails way". Rails provides 3 separate environments (dev, testing, production), and does its best to keep them separate...

Update: you'll probably be very interested in Rails 3.2 (http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/20/rails-3-2-rc1-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store) which will have a much faster dev mode.

Comment: Hi. I am not interested in developing in a live environment, that would be insane :)
It's just that this API is used together with a web application under development, and with 10-12 requests per page load there is quite a difference having the page load in 5-7 seconds extra per page load vs less than half a second.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I'd suggest you have your Rails app in production, and use a dev app when you locate an issue. Your best bet is probably developing a test suite using your API and recording the HTTP calls with VCR (https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr). That way, you can run your test against the production app (for speed) and if you have issues, run it against the dev app (for the log messages).

Comment: I've updated my answer: it seems Rails 3.2 might be the answer to your needs (or at least go a long way).

Comment: David, you are spot on. Quoting from the link you sent:
_**Faster dev mode & routing**_

_The most noticeable new feature is that development mode got a ton and a half faster. Inspired by Active Reload, we now only reload classes from files you’ve actually changed. The difference is dramatic on a larger application._

Answer (score 0):

Insane, but awesome:
http://florianhanke.tumblr.com/post/319854385/ruby-on-speed-unicorn-forking-gc-off-harakiri